# How can i copy the files in the List<string> to another directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Without deleting or renaming the files in any of the directories.
Just to copy the files so they will be in both directories in same order.

I did:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AnimatedGifFiles.Count; i++)
                    {

                    }
```

AnimatedGifFiles is List

For example the first file in the List is like this:

C:\Users\temp\radar012929.gif

So to copy this file to another directory for example to C:\Users\temp1

Comment: What is the problem that you are seeking help with ? Is it that you dont know that the System.IO.File.Copy method exists ? Is that possible ?

Comment: `System.IO.File.Copy(AnimatedGifFiles[i], @"C:\Users\temp1\newFileName.gif");`

Comment: Next time please do some research before asking, You are not the first one to do this in computer history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using System.IO, you can iterate over your source directory and copy to target if the target directory doesn't already have the file in it.

```
public void CopyFiles(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (var fileName in files)
    {
        string targetFile = Path.Combine(targetDir, (new FileInfo(fileName)).Name);
        if (File.Exists(targetFile) == false)
            File.Copy(fileName, targetFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's my mistake i don't need to copy all the files in the sourceDir to the targetDir but to copy only the files that are in the AnimatedGifFiles List since in the sourceDir i have a lot of files but i need to copy only the files that are in the List. It must be the files from the List and not all the files in the sourceDir.

Comment: You can use your `AnimatedGifFiles` since it is a List in the foreach statement, and it would do exactly what you stated for just the files you want. You could also add linq to the `GetFiles` to determine the gif files, such as `Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir).Where(f => f.EndsWith(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray()`